# Get parent process information at runtime on iOS application

Tags: ios, pid, bsd, sysctl

I'm trying to obtain some process information at runtime on iOS, particularly the parent process name.
While I'm able to obtain the current process name, it seems that I can't to do the same for its parent.
Here is what I'm doing:

```
static inline bool is_debugserver_present() {
    int                 err;
    int                 mib[4];
    struct kinfo_proc   info;
    size_t              size;

    // Initialize the flags so that, if sysctl fails for some bizarre
    // reason, we get a predictable result.

    info.kp_proc.p_flag = 0;

    // Initialize mib, which tells sysctl the info we want, in this case
    // we're looking for information about a the parent process ID.

    mib[0] = CTL_KERN;
    mib[1] = KERN_PROC;
    mib[2] = KERN_PROC_PID;
    mib[3] = getppid();

    // Call sysctl.

    size = sizeof(info);
    int n = sizeof(mib) / sizeof(*mib);
    err = sysctl(mib, n, &info, &size, NULL, 0);

    return (strncmp(info.kp_proc.p_comm, "launchd", sizeof("launchd") - 1) != 0);
}
```

The problem is that the call to `sysctl` always return -1 thus an error.
The parent process id obtained by `getppid()`is that same if I ask to the current process for its `kp_eproc.e_ppid`.
Am I missing something?

Comment: On a clean iOS device, the `getppid()` returns `1` when no debugger is attached. If you attach XCode, you will get a different parent pid.  It is likely to be the `/Developer/usr/bin/debugserver`.  Did you try  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1361/_index.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** obtain the information of other processes since iOS 9. `sysctl` is sandboxed now. You can do this only in a iDevice **previous iOS 9** or a Simulator.

> sysctl() retrieves system information for processes with appropriate privileges
>
> iOS apps are not permitted to see what other apps are running
>
> In iOS 9, the sandbox now prevents a process from accessing the kern.proc,
> kern.procargs, and kern.procargs2 values for other processes

see:

- [WWDC Privacy Introduction](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/703/)
- [Privacy and your app](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/703kp2dwbwkr/703/703_privacy_and_your_app.pdf?dl=1) (Page 29)